# How to Change HTML Elements When Window Gets Too Small?

Tags: javascript, html, resize

So here's what I've got:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Fonts!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="Hagin">Hello.</h1>
    <h2 id="Hagin2">Goodbye.</h2>

    <p class="Glober">Hello. This is a paragraph. It is meant to test this font. What do you think? Do you like this font? I think I do, although I'm not sure. That's why I'm writing this paragraph. Eh? Bigger you say? I agree. Let's make it bigger. Yeah, you know what, I'm using this. Allong with that Hagin thing. Some sexy shit.</p>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onresize = function() {
        var width = window.innerWidth;
        var h1 = document.getElementById("Hagin");
        var h2 = document.getElementById("Hagin2");

        if (width < 1000) {
            h1.fontFamily = "Sans";
        }
    };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Right now, I'm just trying to get the font to change to Sans when the window gets below 1000px in width. It's not working... nothing happens. No errors reported in the console. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what CSS media queries are for. Add this at the end of (or after) your existing CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 999px) {
  #Hagin {
    font-family: Sans; 
  }
}
```

or, if you want it applied to *all* `h1` tags:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 999px) {
  h1 {
    font-family: Sans; 
  }
}
```

Comment: Wait, so I don't even need Javascript for this? Do you need Javascript for ANYTHING related to styling?

Comment: For "anything"? Sure, probably. For changing fonts, size, visibility, position based on screen size? Nope.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `style` object which has that property. What you're currently doing is attaching a property named `fontFamily` to `h1`

```
if (width < 1000) {
    h1.style.fontFamily = "Sans";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create css cases using media queries. Look it up - [link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)